# Need Username and Password

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Kubuntu 12.04.3 LTS and used unetbootin to install onto a flashdrive . When run the installation asks for a Username and Password. What are they?

Comment: You should choose a username and password to continue for installation which will be required for administrating (install, remove applications etc.)

Comment: It is asking you to PICK a username and password.

Answer (score 1):

In the installation setup, it should just ask you for the username and password:
[image]

The installation instructions are [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support).